# whats wrong with my magento installation?

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I'm trying to install magento2 on my laptop,I just installed mysql, PHP, phpmyadmin and downloaded magento from official site I've also done with the apache2 settings but when I hit http://localhost/magento this comes up instead of installation can anyone help me?[image: my local site looks like]

My apache status 
[image]

Comment: Your php isn't being parsed. Make sure apache is running. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5121589/3163075)

Comment: that what I see in apache status can this be helpful to us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your php isn't being parsed. Make sure apache is running. See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5121589/3163075)

Based on your screenshot it seems you are having a [AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2268992) error?

Follow the tips [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/256013/could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-name) ...

> i.e. create new file in /etc/apache2/conf-available/fqdn.conf
>
> containing ... ServerName localhost

Comment: Thanks a lot, for your FYI, I just reinstalled the php7 and after doing this fqdn.conf thing it worked thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

I was just missing php-dom extensions so just installed

> sudo apt-get install php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0-cli php7.0-common php7.0-mbstring php7.0-gd php7.0-intl php7.0-xml php7.0-mysql php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-zip

after installing when I restart apache only blank page loads up then a friend @Anima-t3d help me

> Your php isn't being parsed. Make sure apache is running.
>
> Based on your screenshot it seems you are having a AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name error?

then is added a conf file /etc/apache2/conf-available/fqdn.conf with content "ServerName localhost" as he said and it just worked.